# Calculating a checksum in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, checksum

I have a database field of Brazilian CPF numbers and want to check for their validity.  These are 11 digit strings which are 9 digits and 2 checksum digits.

I currently implemented the checksum in MS Excel (see below) but I'd like to figure out a way to do it in SQL.

Checksum works as follows:  (Hold on tight, this is nuts.)

- The CPF number is written in the form ABCDEFGHI / JK or directly as
  ABCDEFGHIJK, where the digits can not all be the same as each other.
- The J is called 1st digit check of the CPF number.
- The K is called the 2nd check digit of the CPF number.

First digit (J):

- Multiply each digit of the first 9 by a constant:
  `10*A + 9*B + 8*C + 7*D + 6*E + 5*F + 4*G + 3*H + 2*I`
- Divide this sum by 11 and if the remainder is 0 or 1, J will be 0. If the remainder is >=2, J will be `11 - remainder`.

Second digit (K):  (Same calculation but including digit J)

- Multiply each digit of the first 10 by a constant:
  `11A + 10B + 9C + 8D + 7E + 6F + 5G + 4H + 3I + 2J`
- Divide this sum by 11 and if the remainder is 0 or 1, K will be 0. If the remainder is >=2, K will be `11 - remainder`.

--Implementation in MS Excel--
Assuming the CPF is in A2.
Optimizations here are welcome but not really the point of this question.
Digit J: `=IF(MOD(SUM(MID($A2,1,1)*10,MID($A2,2,1)*9,MID($A2,3,1)*8,MID($A2,4,1)*7,MID($A2,5,1)*6,MID($A2,6,1)*5,MID($A2,7,1)*4,MID($A2,8,1)*3,MID($A2,9,1)*2),11)<=1,NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT($A2,2),1))=0,NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT($A2,2),1))=(11-MOD(SUM(MID($A2,1,1)*10,MID($A2,2,1)*9,MID($A2,3,1)*8,MID($A2,4,1)*7,MID($A2,5,1)*6,MID($A2,6,1)*5,MID($A2,7,1)*4,MID($A2,8,1)*3,MID($A2,9,1)*2),11)))`
Digit K:
`=IF(MOD(SUM(MID($A2,1,1)*11,MID($A2,2,1)*10,MID($A2,3,1)*9,MID($A2,4,1)*8,MID($A2,5,1)*7,MID($A2,6,1)*6,MID($A2,7,1)*5,MID($A2,8,1)*4,MID($A2,9,1)*3,MID($A2,10,1)*2),11)<=1,NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT($A2,1),1))=0,NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT($A2,1),1))=(11-MOD(SUM(MID($A2,1,1)*11,MID($A2,2,1)*10,MID($A2,3,1)*9,MID($A2,4,1)*8,MID($A2,5,1)*7,MID($A2,6,1)*6,MID($A2,7,1)*5,MID($A2,8,1)*4,MID($A2,9,1)*3,MID($A2,10,1)*2),11)))`

Comment: I guess all you need to know is that there is a substr function in Oracle. 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My test table:

```
-- Create a table called CPF
CREATE TABLE CPF(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, No integer);

-- Create few records in this table 
INSERT INTO CPF VALUES(1, 12345678901);
```

My nested [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1a3d/15/0):

```
SELECT No, 
(CASE WHEN (J != J2) THEN 'J wrong!' ELSE 'J ok!' END) as Jchk,
(CASE WHEN (K != K2) THEN 'K wrong!' ELSE 'K ok!' END) as Kchk
FROM 
(SELECT No, J, K,
(CASE WHEN MJ < 2 THEN 0 ELSE 11 - MJ END) as J2,
(CASE WHEN MK < 2 THEN 0 ELSE 11 - MK END) as K2
FROM 
(SELECT No, J, K,
MOD(10*A + 9*B + 8*C + 7*D + 6*E + 5*F + 4*G + 3*H + 2*I, 11) as MJ,
MOD(11*A + 10*B + 9*C + 8*D + 7*E + 6*F + 5*G + 4*H + 3*I + 2*J, 11) as MK 
FROM 
 (SELECT
  No,
  substr(to_char(No), 1, 1) as A,
  substr(to_char(No), 2, 1) as B,
  substr(to_char(No), 3, 1) as C,
  substr(to_char(No), 4, 1) as D,
  substr(to_char(No), 5, 1) as E,
  substr(to_char(No), 6, 1) as F,
  substr(to_char(No), 7, 1) as G,
  substr(to_char(No), 8, 1) as H,
  substr(to_char(No), 9, 1) as I,
  substr(to_char(No), 10, 1) as J,
  substr(to_char(No), 11, 1) as K
  FROM CPF)))
  ;
```

Comment: Added a regex to check for all digits being the same and added a check that the length doesn't exceed 11 chars.
`(CASE WHEN length(CPF)>11 OR regexp_like (CPF, '^(\d)\1*$') OR (J!=J2) OR (K!=K2) THEN 'INVALID' ELSE 'VALID' END) as CPF_VALID`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table with an `id` primary key column and a `cpf` column that is `NUMBER(9,0)` data type then something like:

```
WITH digits ( id, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         MOD( TRUNC( cpf / 1e8 ), 10 ),
         MOD( TRUNC( cpf / 1e7 ), 10 ),
         MOD( TRUNC( cpf / 1e6 ), 10 ),
         MOD( TRUNC( cpf / 1e5 ), 10 ),
         MOD( TRUNC( cpf / 1e4 ), 10 ),
         MOD( TRUNC( cpf / 1e3 ), 10 ),
         MOD( TRUNC( cpf / 1e2 ), 10 ),
         MOD( TRUNC( cpf / 1e1 ), 10 ),
         MOD( TRUNC( cpf / 1e0 ), 10 )
  FROM   your_table
),
values1 ( id, j, k ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         MOD( 10*A +  9*B +  8*C +  7*D +  6*E +  5*F +  4*G +  3*H + 2*I, 11 ),
         11*A + 10*B +  9*C +  8*D +  7*E +  6*F +  5*G +  4*H + 3*I
  FROM   digits
),
values2 ( id, j, k ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         CASE WHEN j <= 1 THEN 0 ELSE 11 - j END,
         MOD( k + 2 * CASE WHEN j <= 1 THEN 0 ELSE 11 - j END, 11 )
  FROM   values1
)
SELECT id,
       j,
       CASE WHEN k <= 1 THEN 0 ELSE 11 - k END AS k
FROM   values2
```

Comment: First off, thanks for having a go. Looking at this is assumes I'm starting with a 9 digit string and adding the checkdigits. I'm starting with an 11 digit string and comparing.

Answer (score 0):

@SAR622: great question and thanks for the algorithm.

Here is a t-SQL solution for SQL Server, just in case. Note that [Cadastro de Pessoas Físicas (CPF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastro_de_Pessoas_F%C3%ADsicas) numbers can only have 11 digits (pre-panded by zeros), that is they cannot exceed 10^12-1. If you note 14 digit numbers in your dataset, these are likely to be [Cadastro Nacional da Pessoa Jurídica (CNPJ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNPJ) numbers issued to business (or typos or something else). The fake CPF and CNPJ numbers can be generated (in bulk) and validated (individually) [here](http://www.ssngenerator.com/sqlgenerator). Also [this site](http://cnpj.info/busca) provides more info about a business located by its CNPJ (think of it as an implicit CNPJ validation). When validating a CPF number remember to check if the number is in range [0, 10^12-1]. You may need to remove any punctuation symbols and other invalid characters (as users, we tend to make typos).

This input table has top 5 invalid CPF numbers and bottom 4 valid ones:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#x') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #x;
CREATE TABLE #x  (CPF BIGINT default NULL);
INSERT INTO #x (CPF) VALUES (12345678900);
INSERT INTO #x (CPF) VALUES (11);
INSERT INTO #x (CPF) VALUES (1010101010101010);
INSERT INTO #x (CPF) VALUES (11111179011525590);
INSERT INTO #x (CPF) VALUES (-32081397641);
INSERT INTO #x (CPF) VALUES (00000008726210061);
INSERT INTO #x (CPF) VALUES (56000608314);
INSERT INTO #x (CPF) VALUES (73570630706);
INSERT INTO #x (CPF) VALUES (93957133564);
```

The following t-SQL function modularizes implementation, but will likely be slower than the raw t-SQL that follows. Alternatively, you can create a t-SQL function with a TABLE input/output or a stored procedure.

```
ALTER FUNCTION fnIsCPF(@n BIGINT) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @isValid BIT = 0;
    IF (@n > 0 AND @n < 100000000000)
    BEGIN
        --Parse out numbers
        DECLARE @a TINYINT = FLOOR( @n / 10000000000)% 10;
        DECLARE @b TINYINT = FLOOR( @n / 1000000000)% 10;
        DECLARE @c TINYINT = FLOOR( @n / 100000000)% 10;
        DECLARE @d TINYINT = FLOOR( @n / 10000000)% 10;
        DECLARE @e TINYINT = FLOOR( @n / 1000000)% 10;
        DECLARE @f TINYINT = FLOOR( @n / 100000)% 10;
        DECLARE @g TINYINT = FLOOR( @n / 10000)% 10;
        DECLARE @h TINYINT = FLOOR( @n / 1000)% 10;
        DECLARE @i TINYINT = FLOOR( @n / 100)% 10;

        DECLARE @j TINYINT =  ISNULL(NULLIF(NULLIF(11-( 10*@a + 9*@b + 8*@c + 7*@d + 6*@e + 5*@f + 4*@g + 3*@h + 2*@i) % 11, 11), 10), 0);
        DECLARE @k TINYINT =  ISNULL(NULLIF(NULLIF(11 - (11*@a +10*@b + 9*@c + 8*@d + 7*@e + 6*@f + 5*@g + 4*@h + 3*@i + 2 * @j)% 11, 11), 10), 0);
        RETURN CASE WHEN @j=FLOOR(@n / 10)% 10 AND @k=FLOOR(@n)% 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    END;
    RETURN @isValid;
END;
```

The output is:

```
SELECT CPF, isValid=dbo.fnIsCPF(CPF) FROM #x

CPF                 isValid
12345678900         0
11                  0
1010101010101010    0
11111179011525590   0
-32081397641        0
8726210061          1
56000608314         1
73570630706         1
93957133564         1
```

t-SQL for a table:

```
WITH digits ( CPF, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i ) AS (
  SELECT CPF,
    FLOOR( CPF / 10000000000)% 10,
    FLOOR( CPF / 1000000000)% 10,
    FLOOR( CPF / 100000000)% 10,
    FLOOR( CPF / 10000000)% 10,
    FLOOR( CPF / 1000000)% 10,
    FLOOR( CPF / 100000)% 10,
    FLOOR( CPF / 10000)% 10,
    FLOOR( CPF / 1000)% 10,
    FLOOR( CPF / 100)% 10
  FROM   #x
),
jk ( CPF, j, k ) AS (
  SELECT CPF, ISNULL(NULLIF(NULLIF(11-( 10*A + 9*B + 8*C + 7*D + 6*E + 5*F + 4*G + 3*H + 2*I) % 11, 11), 10), 0),
    11*A +10*B + 9*C + 8*D + 7*E + 6*F + 5*G + 4*H + 3*I
  FROM digits
),
jk2 ( CPF, j, k ) AS (
  SELECT CPF, j, ISNULL(NULLIF(NULLIF(11 - (k + 2 * j)% 11, 11), 10), 0)
  FROM jk
)
SELECT CPF, isValid=CASE WHEN CPF>0 AND CPF<99999999999 AND j=FLOOR( CPF / 10)% 10 AND k=FLOOR( CPF)% 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM jk2
```

yielding the same output.